# Cambiar color botón VB Net

Tags: vb.net, vb

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa para regalarle a un amigo en el que, entre otras cosas, va a tener que descifrar un código incrustado en una imagen. El caso es que quiero ocultar botones en la imagen a modo que se fusionen con la imagen.

Tras muchos años sin programar no me acuerdo de mucho. Quiero que al cargarse el formulario, los botones aparezcan de un color determinado mediante RGB; Con backcolor debería de poderse pero al poner en el Form_Load:

```
Me.Bt1.BackColor = RGB (255, 255, 2)
```

me indica que

> el valor de tipo Integer no se puede convertir en color.

Decir que son varios botones y que la forma de resolver 1 me resolvería lo de todos. ¿Alguna idea alguien de cómo proceder?

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes asegurar que los valores defines para los colores RGB sean valores enteros  y usar el método `FromArgb()`, el primer parámetro es el "alpha":

```
Me.Bt1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 2)
```

Puedes usar también el método `FromArgb()` para definir el color de fondo para tu botón de esta forma, definiendo los valores hexadecimales:

```
Me.Bt1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(&HFF, &HFF, &H02)
```

Comment: Gracias!!! Funcionó perfectamente. Ya puedo acabar lo que tengo planificado.